# python3 pdfnup alternative

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

im trying to use pypdf to edit my pdfs but when i try to install pdfnup package using  `./bin/pip3 install pdfnup` i get an error saying

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-leb0bp2j/pdfnup_4441468f5c9a4f4584a752d4b86d18e3/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
          import ez_setup
        File "/tmp/pip-install-leb0bp2j/pdfnup_4441468f5c9a4f4584a752d4b86d18e3/ez_setup.py", line 94
          except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized
      [end of output]
```

is there a way to install that package or use an alternative way with pypdf?
(linux, venv, python3.11)

Comment: pdfly has `2-up` and works with pypdf: https://pypi.org/project/pdfly/ .

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `pdfnup` isn't compatible with Python3.
If you can use Python2 you should be able to pip install it, if you can't use Python2 I suggest you to dig to see if a fork exist and is compatible with Python3 or to search another lib that you can use !

You can try to install https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/user/installation.html it should work with Python3.11 !

Comment: i have pypdt package installed. it dosn't have the pdfnup functionallity. i couldn't find any fork.

Comment: @amirmohammad-firouzfar have you tried to install pypdf2 ?

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.